# move an xcode 4.5.1 project to different folder

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a rather large application in xcode and wish to move the files somewhere else on my computer.

Could this process be as simple as dragging the project folder to a different place in finder or will something mess up?

Comment: copy the folder. paste it somewhere else. open the .xcodeproj file in the new folder. if everything worked the project should open from there and you can delete the old one. i see no reason why it should not work, but better keep the original there in case something goes wrong :)

Comment: Whoa! A question tagged `xcode` that **is actually** about Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the .xcodeproj files will not cause any issues as long as xcode is closed when you migrate the files and you delete the old files.

When xcode is next launched, if you browse and open the proj file from the new directory, all the references will be set to the correct destinations

Comment: Wrong. You will get this error if you change the destination: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

on a side note it always pays to keep the old files in a .old folder when migrating projects to avoid issues.

As long as the files are kept in their respective folders, next time you run a build in xcode, the references to the new directory the proj file is in will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

As another side note, i just tried to do this and it messed up for me. Typically, any references will switch over, but i had a linker error: ld. it was trying to link to an external library that was contained within the old folder. i had to go to build settings->search paths->library search paths and change that to the new folder location. that worked for me.